# The JSON structure with Javascript

Tags: javascript, json

I have a JSON file with next structure :

```
            {"coordinates":
                    [[3.562251301440316,-76.2809944152832],
                    [3.54117750673122,-76.28803253173828],
                    [3.5488874874187673,-76.31258010864258],
                    [3.5643072556238033,-76.3139533996582],
                    [3.569104464176614,-76.29936218261719],
                    [3.565335230992449,-76.2894058227539],
                    [3.562593960789916,-76.28219604492188]]
            }
```

The correct structure is :

```
            {
                "u1":   {"a":3.5649925726638965, "o":-76.32013320922852},
                "u2":   {"a":3.5432335078647568, "o":-76.30863189697266},
                "u3":   {"a":3.5581393792979417, "o":-76.2835693359375},
                "u4":   {"a":3.571503059060428, "o":-76.29026412963867},
                "u5":   {"a":3.5774995188413183, "o":-76.3081169128418},
                "u6":   {"a":3.5804120708676126, "o":-76.32476806640625}
            }
```

question:
What change I must make for work with the following code javascript with the first coordinates?

I have ready the second coordinate file and your function is ok, but  I must many changes manually.

the Javascript code for work with this coordinates is

```
            function initialize() 
                {   
                    var hr = new XMLHttpRequest();
                    hr.open("GET", "mylist.json", true);
                    hr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/json", true);

                    var la, lo ;        

                    hr.onreadystatechange = function()
                    {               
                        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('mapa'), {
                        zoom: 12,       
                        center: new google.maps.LatLng(3.555, -76.29),      
                        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
                         });             
                        var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
                        var marker, i;
                        var pathCoordinates = new google.maps.MVCArray();       
                        var arr = [];

                        if(hr.readyState == 4 && hr.status == 200)
                        {
                            var data = JSON.parse(hr.responseText);         
                            for(var obj in data)
                            {                       
                                    la =  data[obj].a;
                                    lo =  data[obj].o;                                              
                              marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                              position: new google.maps.LatLng( la , lo),
                              map: map});                
                            }                   
                        }
                    } 
                    hr.send(null);  
                }
```

Comment: If the items are ordered, it would be weird not to put them in an array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the map/reduce function to parse your object:

```js
var coords = {
  "coordinates": [
    [3.562251301440316, -76.2809944152832],
    [3.54117750673122, -76.28803253173828],
    [3.5488874874187673, -76.31258010864258],
    [3.5643072556238033, -76.3139533996582],
    [3.569104464176614, -76.29936218261719],
    [3.565335230992449, -76.2894058227539],
    [3.562593960789916, -76.28219604492188]
  ]
}

var obj = coords.coordinates.map(function(item, idx) {
  return {
    "a": item[0],
    "o": item[1]
  }
}).reduce(function(previousValue, currentValue, index, vector){
    previousValue["u" + (index+1)] = currentValue
    return previousValue;
}, {});

console.log(obj)
```

Answer (score 1):

Your question isn't exactly clear to me, but if you're trying to parse the first structure, it would be something like

```
var data = JSON.parse(hr.responseText).coordinates;
data.forEach(function(pt) {
    la = pt[0];
    lo = pt[1];
    // ...
});
```

Comment: yes, that is the solution ... I'm sorry , I don't speak english . I'm learning english in this moment...
your answer is perfect for my problem..
thank you